# World of Warcraft Lua - If statement flow

Tags: lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

I'm trying to create an addon for World of Warcraft. I have created a function that checks whether a buff has been added to the current player.

```
Button:RegisterEvent("UNIT_AURA");
local function auraGained(self, event, ...)
    if (UnitAura("player", "Heating Up")) then
             if (heatingUpIsActive ~= 1) then
             heatingUpIsActive = heatingUpIsActive + 1
            print (heatingUpIsActive) 
            end 
    end
Button:SetScript("OnEvent", auraGained);
```

This works great, but how do I check if `UnitAura` is *not* `"Heating Up"`?

Also, I would prefer if `heatingUpIsActive` were a `boolean`, but it seems to not like when I do that. What is the correct way to create a `boolean` in Lua?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function isn't checking the aura that caused the event. It's looking for "Heating Up" any time any `UNIT_AURA` event comes by. In fact, it looks like the `UNIT_AURA` event doesn't actually tell you which aura triggered it. So you can't "check if `UnitAura` is *not* `"Heating Up"`", because you simply don't know what aura caused the event. Perhaps it was even several auras at once.

However, the event does tell you what unit got the aura. It's the first vararg. You should probably check to make sure it's `player` before doing something

```
local unitid = ...
if unitid ~= "player" then return end
```

Also, you didn't explain what problems you had with booleans. You should just be able to say something like

```
if not heatingUpIsActive then
    heatingUpIsActive = true
    -- do whatever you want
end
```

although I never saw any declaration of the variable in your code. It's a bad idea to use globals for things like this, so you should declare

```
local heatingUpIsActive
```

before the function declaration, e.g.

```
local heatingUpIsActive
local function auraGained(self, event, ...)
    -- ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! To my understanding (and forgive me if I'm incorrect about this), what I am accomplishing here is that the `UNIT_AURA` event is called whenever a unit in the area gains or loses an aura. Ultimately what I want to do is when "Heating Up" is active on the player, set `heatingUpIsActive` to true. To my logic, when "Heating Up" is no longer on the player, `UNIT_AURA` would be called, I would detect that it wasn't there, and set `heatingUpIsActive` to false. Would this be an incorrect way of thinking about this problem?

Comment: And to answer your question about booleans, in this code snippit, I declared a variable `heatingUpIsActive = true` and the addon wouldn't load, but worked fine when I declared it as `heatingUpIsActive = 1`. So that confused me 0_0

Comment: @GreenWire: Your understanding about `UNIT_AURA` sounds correct to me. If you want to set `heatingUpIsActive` to `false` when the aura is gone, just add `else heatingUpIsActive = false`.

Comment: @GreenWire: And when you say "the addon wouldn't load", what exactly was wrong? Did you get some error? Maybe there's a global var named `heatingUpIsActive` from another addon that needs to be a number? Using a local as I suggested would fix that.

Comment: lol...I must have just been suffering growing pains with this. It works great now, booleans and all. My thought process needed to change, because `if (UnitAura ("player", "Heating Up")` is not true, then the `else` takes care of the rest. Duh. Sorry for being a nooblit, and thanks so much for your help! You're amazing!

Comment: I've taken your advice and put it into my code. If you can, I have another question that I've posted that is related to this one. You can check it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823838/world-of-warcraft-lua-changing-framesetattribute